# website on server as "localhost"

Tags: nginx, web, localhost

I am transfering project from one server to another, but I want to test it on server before I'll transfer dns recods. Is there any possibilty to test it on server like "localhost" with nginx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for something that runs a local Apache2 server on your computer. Unfortunately there is no program, that I know of, that will run Nginx instead of Apache2.

I'll list them here: AMPPS, XAMPP and more.....

You can basically host local apache, sql, ftp servers.

I hope this helped